# Evaluation of a Landau symbol in expressions

Tags: number-theory, notation, asymptotics

I've encountered an expression which uses a Landau symbol (big O) within an expression. I'm only familiar with this syntax for expressing functional complexity. I'm wondering how this might be interpreted and evaluated. I encountered this expression when deriving a degree distribution for a Bianconi-Barabasi network model (Eq 6.36, [Source](http://networksciencebook.com/chapter/6#advanced-6a)). I've been unable to find info on this usage, other than it represents a substitution under certain (asymptotic) conditions.

$$⟨∑_jη_jk_j⟩=^{t→∞}Cmt(1−O(t^{−ε}))$$
$$ε = (1 − \mbox{max}_ηβ(η)) > 0$$

Comment: In analytic number theory at least, the Landau $O$-notation means the following: $O(t^{-\epsilon})$ stands for some (unspecified) function $f(t)$ with the property that there exists a constant $C>0$ with $|f(t)| \le Ct^{-\epsilon}$.

Comment: That's my best assumption so far. The contained expression is proportional, up to a constant, with another expression. I'm guessing in this particular case it's saying "I swapped an expression for another that is representative of it's complexity in the case of the limit of t". So I guess this expression can't be evaluated in a real sense, but merely gauge relative rates of change.